# How to extract specific folder contents from jar file using gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am new in gradle and looking a Gradle task to extract some specific folder from dependency(jar file). I have created a nativelib folder under src/main/nativeLib and want to copy all native libraries which are inside of native jar.
Basically this native jar already added in my central repo and it contains native libs(.so files) inside a lib. I have added this native jar as dependencies in my gradle.build and now want to first extract all contents from this jar-->lib folder and place in nativelib and then set a jniLibs like this:

```
 android {
  sourceSets
        {
            main {
                jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/nativelib']
            }
        }
   }
```

gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.hospitality.android:liblinphone-sdk-native:3.2.1'
```

}

Can someone help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

 android {
  sourceSets
        {
            main {
                jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/nativelib']
            }
        }
   }

build.dependsOn(copyToLib)

task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
    into "$buildDir/output/libs"
    from configurations.runtime
}
```

see if this works and it copies to output/libs.

Comment: Can you please explain to me,  What should be a path to my liblinphone-sdk-native ? and where i need to use this copy { } inside my gradle build ?

Comment: Do i need to define runtime as well: just adding a task copyToLib given an error in gradle:  Error:(136, 0) Could not find property 'runtime' on configuration container. I am using gradle version 2.7

Comment: do you have apply plugin: 'java' and apply plugin: 'application'? updated code.